# extracting value from dictionary represented as string

Tags: python, json

I had input data file given as

```
obama president    "[{""b"":0,""e"":6,""v"":""obama""}]"
beatles band    "[{""b"":0,""e"":8,""v"":""beatles""}]"
```

and I want an output file with the value "v" extracted from the inside dictionary as

```
   obama president /t  obama;  
   beatles band /t     beatles;
```

I was using a code to strip items and get to the dictionary but I am getting errors perhaps because of keys have two double quotes "" for both beginning and ending.

```
import json
with open("NER_data_0_out","wt") as o, open('NER_data_0') as f:
    for line in f:
        l = line.strip().split("\t")
        h = l[1].strip('"')[1:-1]
        print(h)
        d = json.loads(h)
        print(d)
```

and I get the error. I suppose I need to strip some quotes before?

```
Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 4 (char 3)
```

Comment: having doubled quotes like that isn't valid, it is Matlab string literal notation.  if you did something like `json.loads(h.replace('""', '"'))` that might work for you, although you are also missing end curly brace so idk what is going on with that data...

Answer (score 0):

The error message is complaining that the input is not valid JSON. Besides the double quotes, there is also an opening `{` for an object in the array `[]`, but it does not properly close.

Instead of using JSON a workaround, you could use is RegEx.

This regex will look for the following sequence `""v"":""TEXT_HERE""`.

`\"\"v\"\"\:\"\"(.+)\"\"`

Here is an example.

```
import json
import re

with open("input") as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.findall(r"\"\"v\"\"\:\"\"(.+)\"\"", line)
        print(m[0])
```

You can play around with this regex and learn more about how it works here https://regex101.com/r/iy2pHc/1.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
import re

with open("FILE_TO_READ","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        v =  re.findall('"([^"]*)"', line)[-2]
        line = line.split('"', 1)[0]
        print(f'{line} /t {v}')
```